# Why is a website assigned the same ip address each time?

Tags: ip, server

1. Why is a website assigned the same ip address each time?
2. Discuss with a suitable example whether a server can be assigned two different IP addresses.

Would appreciate some help in these two questions.
Thanks

Comment: This is not a homework platform. Just use wikipedia or google ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question #1:

Short answer: websites are assigned the same IP address so that Web clients will send requests to the proper system.

Long answer: Web clients rarely connect to servers using IP addresses directly.  Instead, clients use domain names like `www.google.com`.  DNS software then maps the name to the address.

Thus changing a Web server address should be easy - just change the name mapping.  But for performance reasons, name mappings are cached.  So if the mapping is changed, some caches will have the old mapping for a period of time (called the Time To Live, or TTL).  So changing a Web server address isn't trivial.

Question #2:

There are a number of circumstances where a server can have more than one IP address:

- The server is hosting multiple VMs.  Each VM has its own IP address.
- The server is hosting websites for multiple companies.  Each website has its own IP address.
- The server is doing routing between two subnets.  It will have separate IP addresses for each subnet it is on.